How to filter projects based on date on Openproject API.v3
From my openproject API  i want to retrive all the work packages for project id=65 for author=32 and created between dates 2024-10-01 and 2024-10-23. Without the filter created_at, ny GET works correctly and returns all the project for this author.
When i tried to insert dates on filter i am getting always the same error message with status "400 Bad Request".
This is the end point i am using on Postman:
http:10.10.10.10:30100/api/v3/projects/65/work_packages?filters=[{"author": {"operator":"=","values": ["32"]}},{"created_at":{"operator":"<>","values":["2024-10-01","2014-10-23"]}}

This is the answer i am getting :
{
"_type": "Error",
"errorIdentifier": "urn:openproject-org:api:v3:errors:InvalidQuery",
"message": "Created on Operator is not set to one of the allowed values."

}
i have tried with ioperator > , >=, <, <=, <> and it's nor working.
using operator <>d does not generate an error , but is not returning the work_packages i want.

Using the <>d should yield the expected results as it is the correct one to limit the results to be between two dates. The reason why you are then not getting the work packages you expect must be something else.
A good way to construct an API request is currently through the UI which as of now still used the API itself. So if you open the network tab in the browser and then select the filters you desire, that will give you the URL to call outside of the browser as well. If the results in and outside of the browser differ, I would look into authentication.
